# Cannot boot Xen: secureboot forbids loading multiboot2 module

Tags: boot, uefi, 21.04, xen

I've installed `xen-hypervisor-4.11-amd64`, now I wish to boot Xen.

I can't. When I choose corresponding entry from grub I receive following message:

```
Loading Xen 4.11-amd64    
error: Secure boot forbids loading module from .../grub/x86_64-efi/multiboot2.mod
Loading Linux ...
error: Secure boot forbids loading module from .../grub/x86_64-efi/multiboot2.mod
Loading initial ramdisk ...
error: Secure boot forbids loading module from .../grub/x86_64-efi/multiboot2.mod
```

I suspect that module is not signed, however I wish to not disable SecureBoot. What is the cause of this message, and what is the easiest way to fix this problem?

Ubuntu 21.04, Xen: 4.11, kernel: 5.11.0-34-generic